# Unable to import meta graph using tf.train.import_meta_graph, The name '' refers to an Operation not in the graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, returnn

```
OS Platform and Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04

tf.VERSION = 1.13.1                                                            
tf.GIT_VERSION = b'v1.13.1-0-g6612da8951'                                      
tf.COMPILER_VERSION = b'v1.13.1-0-g6612da8951'
Python version: 3.6.10
GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): 4.8.5
CUDA/cuDNN version: 10.2
GPU model and memory: Nvidia Tesla V100, 16gb
```

I am not able to import meta graph.
Even If I define tf.placeholder(name="data", shape=(None,64), dtype=tf.float32), error comes for next layer.
I tried using tf2.0 also. But same issue there.

**Code to reproduce the issue**

```
import tensorflow as tf

model_dir="./model"   # change this line to the directory where checkpoint and models are saved
checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_dir)
input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
clear_devices = True

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)
```

Checkpoint files are attached in [model.zip](https://github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com/45717250/4126895?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200129%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200129T091828Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=982a569208914bcf275b25948081d559585aaf4f308796294888b29d573f123c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=53848409&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3Dmodel.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip).

StackTrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_meta_graph.py", line 11, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)
  File "/home/ubuntu/tf1.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1435, in import_meta_graph
    meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, import_scope, **kwargs)[0]
  File "/home/ubuntu/tf1.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1457, in _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    **kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/tf1.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 852, in import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    ops.prepend_name_scope(value, scope_to_prepend_to_names))
  File "/home/ubuntu/tf1.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3478, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/tf1.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3538, in _as_graph_element_locked
    "graph." % repr(name))
KeyError: "The name 'data' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

Comment: I also tried without session also. Same error in that case also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `graph=tf.Graph()`, otherwise the `import_meta_graph` will import it into the wrong graph.